# adding contents to tab layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I followed the [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) (as well as some other threads here at Stackoverflow..)

Now I want to incorporate twitter client into one of the tabs. The tutorial is this: [Twitter Client](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/67.html)

Thus far I have the following structure:

> > HelloTabWidget.java
> >
> > MyTwitter.java (previously artists.java - also my first tab)
> >
> > AlbumsActitivity.java  (2nd tab)
> >
> > SongsActitivity.java  (3rd tab)

For each of the tabs, I have their own drawable xml (for the icons). I also have main.xml in the layout.

So now I started with the tutorial, but how do I modify main.xml when (1) no graphical display is available, and (2) this main.xml controls only the outline.

Then I thought about creating a mytwitter.xml but how do I tell the actitivty to use mytwitter.xml to display the content (while main.xml keeps the outline of the whole app's layout)?

In summary, how do I specify the content layout for each tab??? I see in HelloTabWidget.java we have setContent (refers to each tab's tab xml).

Thank you very much for any input!

---

**Update**
I am posting codes. 
(1) [HelloTabWidget.java](http://pastebin.com/fc2VGEHt)
(2) [main.xml](http://pastebin.com/VFkMK68u)
(3) [MyTwitter.java](http://pastebin.com/rPAtbT0w)

In the main.xml, I defined tabview2 (linear layout) with a button. I changed the parameter of setContentView to R.id.tabview2, but I got "force to quit"

According to CAT, I have the following errors:

> 05-17 10:29:14.402:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(796): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>
> 05-17 10:29:14.402:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(796):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   start activity
>   ComponentInfo{ywong02.android.HelloTabWidget/ywong02.android.HelloTabWidget.HelloTabWidget}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Your
>   content must have a TabHost whose id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

What should I do? 
Again, I want to display, say, a button on the first tab (namely, MyTwitter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a layout, xml or not, in every activity. I mean every Activity must call setContentView to display its contents. If there's something that you need to reuse you can use the include tag, the same way you use it in JSP.

Comment: Hi Federico. Thank you very much. I am pretty new to android development. I updated my post with some addiitonal information. I tried to do what you said (setContent()). The parameter I used was called "tabview2". This is the content view... all I want is a button. However, I encountered "force to quit". Do you mind to help me more on this? Thanks!

Comment: The logcat error is pretty self-explainatory: "Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost". You haven't included a tabhost with 'android.R.id.tabhost' as id in your xml.